# can't get cron to run scripts

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have spent days trying to understand why previously working scripts in cron.d do not work anymore.

I got frustrated after trying lots of things and deleted them all. I wanted to check why cron is not working. I am logged in as pi.

I created a file in the cron.d directory using nano :

```
* * * * * pi bash //home/pi/cron.sh
```

I checked permissions of the cron file :

```
pi@raspberrypi //etc $ namei -l //etc/cron.d/mycronjobpi
f: //etc/cron.d/mycronjobpi
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root cron.d
-rwxrwxrwx root root mycronjobpi
pi@raspberrypi //etc $
```

I checked the permission of the cron.sh file :

```
pi@raspberrypi //etc $ namei -l //home/pi/cron.sh
f: //home/pi/cron.sh
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x pi   pi   pi
-rwxrwxrwx pi   root cron.sh
```

The script is :

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> //home/pi/crondate.txt
```

bash runs the script when bash is typed otherwise not, despite trying different shebang.

```
pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ bash cron.sh
pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ cron.sh
bash: cron.sh: command not found
```

For information,

```
pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/user/bin


run-parts: executing //etc/cron.d/mycronjobpi
run-parts: failed to exec //etc/cron.d/mycronjobpi: Exec format error
run-parts: //etc/cron.d/mycronjobpi exited with return code 1
```

Please explain why cron does not work despite restarting :
sudo service cron restart.

As can be seen, I believe the file permissions are alright and the scripts work when run directly. Please help.

I have wasted at least a day getting nowhere.
Please help. Please also explain why bash script does not run without bash being typed.

For info

```
pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/user/bin
```

Comment: If the current directory is not in your `PATH`, you need to do `./cron.sh` rather than `cron.sh`.

Comment: @Tom I am assuming that you are referring to the running of the bash script cron.sh. Even when in the directory bash does not run the script without preceeding the filename with bash. pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ bash cron.sh
pi@raspberrypi //home/pi $ cron.sh
bash: cron.sh: command not found

Comment: I wanted to add that I used a nice bit of code I found:  cat cron.sh | sed 's/\r/<CR>/' to check that there was no windows returns in the script.

Comment: I thought I would try something new for me. I used crontab -e and used the same line as in the above cronjob. I did this for pi, and as root using sudo crontab-e. I also added whoami >> //home/pi/crondate.txt to the cron.sh. Interestingly this seemed to work when I took the user out of the line. However, I would like to understand why this did not work with the user, and why the cron.d job did not work.

Comment: you can use the `flag` tag at the bottom of your question to ask a moderator to move this to unix.stackexchange.com , where it is more on topic. Good luck!